# Apply Themes dynamically for UserControl in Silverlight 4.0

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I want to apply themes dynamically for UserControls in silverlight.

I have created 3 projects.

```
1) Contains Themes and Images

2) Contains User Controls

3) My project where I have used my themes and User controls
```

How can I change themes dynamically for user control?

Please suggest me a way.

Comment: Would this help? http://www.pitorque.de/MisterGoodcat/post/Creating-Packs-from-the-Silverlight-Application-Themes.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dynamically apply and change Theme with the Silverlight Toolkit - Laurent Duveau](http://weblogs.asp.net/lduveau/archive/2010/05/31/dynamically-apply-and-change-theme-with-the-silverlight-toolkit.aspx) describes a solution that you could use along with [Creating Packs from the Silverlight Application Themes](http://www.pitorque.de/MisterGoodcat/post/Creating-Packs-from-the-Silverlight-Application-Themes.aspx).

Note that these techniques are specific to **Silverlight 4**, which now supports [Implicit Styles](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Implicit-Styles-in-Silverlight-4.aspx). Much of the existing content on the Internet regarding Silverlight and Themes, describe solutions using ImplicitStyleManager (still applicable to Silverlight 3).